# Turned on a valve, discovered water leaking through basement ceiling

Tags: water, leak

I turned on a valve in a basement ceiling access panel while de-winterizing the house thinking it would open the garage faucet, but instead I heard water gushing through the pipe and down through a pot light in the opposite room.

After turning it off I immediately cut 2 holes in the ceiling to investigate. Was not able to find the end of the copper pipe but noticed it was thinner and flexible. The valve I opened was connected to another valve that converted the 1" copper to a 0.5" copper pipe which was flexible.

Above this room is the kitchen so I thought it was for the fridge water supply. I removed the fridge but saw nothing coming out of the floor, therefore no supply.

The blue valve is off and a couple of fans are drying the carpet. It was silly of me to think the valve would open the faucet in the garage - turns out it was already open and did not have a secondary value concealed.

I guess I don't know what to ask, but what do I do next? I can live with never opening the valve again. Here are some pics:
[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: possibly an outside tap froze and burst

Comment: There is no water leak under or near the blue valve that I opened. Neither is an outdoor faucet near by. The leak could be where the flexible pipe took the biggest bend which is next to the pot light.

Comment: Find the leak. It isn't rocket science. Then revise to ask a specific question. If you don't want to do that, cap the line. Good luck.

Answer (score 1):

If that is now a "dead leg", then you should cap it off at the closest point to its supply line.

Dead legs, or pipe runs that go nowhere, can be the source of contamination etc and need to be avoided.

Comment: Remove it and scrap it, copper has some value.

Answer (score 0):

This is a really vague question, but "what do you do next" would be to open every tap in the house to find out which one *doesn't* have water coming out. That's the one this pipe serves.

Once you determine where the water goes, decide if you can live without water there, and if so, **tag the valve** indicating that there's a broken pipe beyond here and where that pipe leads. That *should* prevent others from opening it and flooding the ceiling again.

If you *can't* live without that water source, you'll have to open walls/floors/ceilings until you find where the actual leak is and repair it.

<sup>Vague questions get vague answers.</sup>

Comment: I understand its vague but it was a dire situation and I posted immediately after the event. Sometimes incomplete questions help spark conversations and solutions that can be helpful to the novice DIYer community. If the question is against the spirit and rulebook of the community, please delete this question. That being said, this valve has been closed since I moved in and all faucets still function. I am unable to find the end of the pipe but @manassehkatz could be right. I will check under the fridge again to find an opening.

Answer (score 0):

My hunch is this **was** the refrigerator ice maker supply. It had problems. Previous owner turned off the valve, cut the copper tubing and let it fall back into the wall (therefore you can't find the end).  Then they installed a new line to the refrigerator from a different location, perhaps from the kitchen sink.

Dry it up. Put a big sign on the valve for the next owner to see. The right thing - but extra work - is to cut and cap the line right after the valve. Then it will be obvious even if the sign falls off.